# Unable to generate a user model in within Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I can run & successfully install the devise gem , but when i try to generate a user model. 
It creates a database file but without the .rb extension

```
20140320203238_devise_create_users
```

so when i run rake db:migrate nothing happens

i have to go and rename the file an add rb before I run the migrate command for it to create a migration

Comment: Is there an actual question? It sounds like you solved the issue. If you think it's an issue with the devise gem I would recommend creating an issue on the project on Github.

Comment: i don't know because i have created many migrations without having to rename the file and cannot find any info on this . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an existing issue associated with `Devise` particularly for Rails version `4.1.0.rc1`. This could be very well the issue here, I can't confirm as you have not mentioned the rails version you are currently using.

I would recommend you to downgrade `Rails` version to `4.0.2` and try again.

You can see the ongoing discussion on this issue at [Devise generator creates failing migration in Rails 4.1.0.rc1](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_composer/issues/282)

Comment: yes ,since i upgraded to 4.0.4 i have had problems with creating user models